# Serialized Arrray in TCPDF not showing properly

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

Good Day

I have a serialized array having records in MYSQL
When I display them browser, results are fine (by unserializing and displaying)
When I show in TCPDF, it returns only one record (total are 2 3 records)

I am putting them in loop and using same logic as using in browser too

Below is the code I am trying in TCPDF

Thanks

```
$query1 = "SELECT * from fine_controls WHERE formid='$emp_id'";
        $resulty = mysqli_query($link, $query1);
        

        while($row22 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulty)){
            $fine_typesR = unserialize($row22['fine_type']);
        }
    foreach ($fine_typesR as $fine_typet) { $f= $fine_typet;    }
  $pdf->writeHTML($f, true, false, false, false, '');
```

Above code shows only one value suppose values are 3 and 7 I get only one record 3. I don't know why is this happening

Thanks

Comment: You have not included the writeHTML inside the loop. (move the closing brace after the writeHTML statement please)

Comment: @KenLee Iknow this but problem is i have a table with $values=table having other rows so I am printing pdf->html in the end how can I put this here? can you guide? like I have <tr>
         <th>abc</th>
         </tr><br /> then other rows and this $f row then so how I can put foreach within the table can you help?

Answer (score 1):

As KenLee said, Put  $pdf->writeHTML in loop too so it worked

Thanks

```
$query1 = "SELECT * from fine_controls WHERE formid='$emp_id'";
        $resulty = mysqli_query($link, $query1);
        

        while($row22 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulty)){
            $fine_typesR = unserialize($row22['fine_type']);
        }
    foreach ($fine_typesR as $fine_typet) { $f= $fine_typet;    
  $pdf->writeHTML($f, true, false, false, false, '');

}
```